# how to keep the key background color changed...?

Tags: android, background

I have custom keyboard with red buttons when I press on the for example number 1 the color changed to blue when I pull my finger from the screen goes back to be red , I want to stay blue anyone knows how to do it here's my color changing (pressing) xml

```
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      >
           <item
      android:state_pressed="true"
       android:drawable="@drawable/pressed" />

   <item
    android:state_checkable="true"
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/download" />


 <item android:drawable="@drawable/red"/>



           </selector>
```

check this:

```
public class BasicOnKeyboardActionListener implements KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener {

private Activity mTargetActivity;



public BasicOnKeyboardActionListener(Activity targetActivity) {



    mTargetActivity = targetActivity;
}

@Override
public void swipeUp() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void swipeRight() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void swipeLeft() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void swipeDown() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onText(CharSequence text) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onRelease(int primaryCode) {

    }

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


  @Override
  public void onPress(int primaryCode) {

    }

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  @Override
  public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes)

{

    long eventTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    KeyEvent event = new KeyEvent(eventTime, eventTime,
            KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, primaryCode, 0,  0 ,0 , 0,
            KeyEvent.FLAG_SOFT_KEYBOARD | KeyEvent.FLAG_KEEP_TOUCH_MODE);

    mTargetActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(event);


}
```

Comment: Pressed,download  are blue color

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Add this methods to the `keyboardListner`
> ```

```
 public class SimpleIME extends InputMethodService
    implements OnKeyboardActionListener{

    private KeyboardView kv;
    private Keyboard keyboard;

    private boolean caps = false;

    @Override
    public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {        

    }

    @Override
    public void onPress(int primaryCode) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onRelease(int primaryCode) {            
    }

    @Override
    public void onText(CharSequence text) {     
    }

    @Override
    public void swipeDown() {   
    }

    @Override
    public void swipeLeft() {
    }

    @Override
    public void swipeRight() {
    }

    @Override
    public void swipeUp() {
    }
}
```

and change the `onpressed` and `OnReleased` color

for more details follow the link...  [click here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-keyboard-on-android--cms-22615)

Comment: check my code it's custom keyboard I'm not extending InputMethodService its for just 1 app

Comment: and when i press the color does change but when i release it goes to its old color

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Button Focused-->
        <item   android:state_focused="true"
                android:state_pressed="false"
                android:drawable="@drawable/blue"
                />
    <!-- Button Focused Pressed-->
        <item   android:state_focused="true"
                android:state_pressed="true"
                android:drawable="@drawable/blue"
                />
    <!-- Button Pressed-->
        <item   android:state_focused="false"
                android:state_pressed="true"
                android:drawable="@drawable/blue"
                />
 <!-- Button not focused and Pressed-->
        <item   android:state_focused="false"
                android:state_pressed="false"
               android:state_selected="true"  
                android:drawable="@drawable/blue"/>

    <!-- Button Default Image-->
        <item   android:drawable="@drawable/red"/>

    </selector>
```

Comment: same ..! it goes to red and back to blue when i release it

Comment: Still doesn't worked :( i searched whole the net and didn't find any solution even after this i need when I backspace the thing i wrote the color backs to red for the key that i pressed and changed the color

Comment: same bro i dont know what we need :(

Comment: bro don't loose hopes just try till the end..i will also keep helping you

Comment: I will try with gridview buttons like keyboard just i need how to diable the button and reenable it when i backspace the number that i write in the edit text

Comment: bro do one thing get the Boolean value if the key board value is pressed and check the condition if the key is pressed then add the color  blue to that..

Comment: bro checkout this https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html and this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html  keep try by changing the states and ask me have any help in this.